# Unmet dependencies installing gnome-shell-extension-weather

Tags: installation, 13.04, apt, dependencies

When I want to install anything with the apt-get I get an error.For example :

```
amin@Amin-PC:~$ sudo apt-get install gnome-shell-extension-weather
[sudo] password for amin: 

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gnome-shell-extension-weather : Depends: seed but it is not going to be installed
 libgtk-3-0 : Depends: libwayland-client0 (>= 1.1.90) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libwayland-cursor0 (>= 1.1.90) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
amin@Amin-PC:~$
```

then i tried :

```
amin@Amin-PC:~$ su -
Password: 
root@Amin-PC:~# apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  java-wrappers p7zip
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libwayland-client0 libwayland-cursor0
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libwayland-client0 libwayland-cursor0
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 226 not upgraded.
26 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/36.7 kB of archives.
After this operation, 155 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
(Reading database ... 208142 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking libwayland-client0:amd64 (from .../libwayland-client0_1.2.0-0ubuntu1~13.04~ricotz0_amd64.deb) ...
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/libwayland-client0_1.2.0-0ubuntu1~13.04~ricotz0_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwayland-client.so.0.1.0', which is also in package libwayland0:amd64 1.0.5-0ubuntu1
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Unpacking libwayland-cursor0:amd64 (from .../libwayland-cursor0_1.2.0-0ubuntu1~13.04~ricotz0_amd64.deb) ...
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/libwayland-cursor0_1.2.0-0ubuntu1~13.04~ricotz0_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwayland-cursor.so.0.0.0', which is also in package libwayland0:amd64 1.0.5-0ubuntu1
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libwayland-client0_1.2.0-0ubuntu1~13.04~ricotz0_amd64.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libwayland-cursor0_1.2.0-0ubuntu1~13.04~ricotz0_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
root@Amin-PC:~#
```

How can i fix it?

Comment: You should update your question with the PPA you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your terminal (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>)

```
sudo -i
dpkg -i --force-overwrite  /var/cache/apt/archives/libwayland-client0_1.2.0-0ubuntu1~13.04~ricotz0_amd64.deb
dpkg -i --force-overwrite  /var/cache/apt/archives/libwayland-cursor0_1.2.0-0ubuntu1~13.04~ricotz0_amd64.deb
```

Comment: Won't this cause wreckage mixing PPA's and official packages?

Comment: No , it will not give you any further problems.